# Courses API not returning material sets

Tags: google-classroom

I'm calling the courses REST API via the javascript library and I am able to get back the courses correctly, also assignments from the assignments endpoint. But, the course objects do not have a materialSets array field. I've tried using the readonly and read/write auth scopes. The course definitely has materials as I can see them if I log in to Google Classroom as a student. Also note that I'm doing OAuth2 authentication as the same student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### At the current stage [Method: courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list) will only return you materials that are bound to a course work

- Materials that are created independently without being a part of an assignment are not returned by this method.
- So currently there is no endpoint to return independent materials.
- However, this issue has already been noticed and there is a 
  [feature request](https://buganizer.corp.google.com/issues/115421140) on Google's Public Issue Tracker asking to implement this endpoint.
- I recommend you to "star" this feature request in order to show that you are also interested in its implementation and thus, increase its visibility.